# Does MediaElement.js support streaming from Amazon S3?

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm using MediaElement.js on a WordPress site and it seems to have issues streaming videos from Amazon. All of the videos in the WordPress library are sent to Amazon S# via another plugin. I get audio but no video. Is there something different I need to do to get MediaElement.js to work for streaming videos from amazon s3? Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Need example webpages please, with what browsers & platforms you have tested on.

Answer (score 2):

For my LinkedIn webinar video I got MediaElement.js Wordpress Plugin to play ball with my Amazon S3 account. You can see it in action here: http://thoughtfaucet.com/making-things/how-to/linkedin-profile-training-video-and-transcript/

For shortcode I used the simple [video src=""] and let it run. Maybe you are using the wrong short code? Or perhaps the file you are uploading isn't one of the supported files?

My LinkedIn profile webinar was a .mov, for what it's worth. I haven't tried other formats.